# move focus to the next entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython

on wxPYTHON , It is default setting to move focus from an TEXTctrl to another by hitting 'TAB key'..
I want to do with hitting ' Enter key ' ..I tried style 'wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER' but it does not work ..Im using windows 8 and here is my code:

```
from wx import *
class test(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent;

        self.basicsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.box=wx.Panel(self,size=(1150,600))
        self.box.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")

        self.basicsizer.Add(self.box, )
        self.SetSizer(self.basicsizer)

        self.MASTER_frames_sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.box.SetSizer(self.MASTER_frames_sizer)

        self.frame1=wx.Panel(self.box,size=(1000,31))
        self.indx=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1,size=(40,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER);
        self.a=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1, size=(100,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER);
        self.b=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1, size=(100,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER) 
        self.c=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1, size=(150,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.d=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1, size=(150,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.e=wx.TextCtrl(self.frame1,size=(180,30),style=wx.TE_CENTRE|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        self.frame1_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.MASTER_frames_sizer.Add(self.frame1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)  # add frame 1
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.e,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.d,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.c,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.b,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.a,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.frame1_sizer.Add(self.indx,flag=wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.frame1.SetSizer(self.frame1_sizer)
        self.Layout()
app = wx.App(False)
frame_ = wx.Frame(None, title="test",size=(1350,800))
gui=test(frame_)
frame_.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Update:
well ..I have solution idea but still missing the syntax..   on tkinter this can be accomplished  by binding the entry widget with the event 'key' or 'keyRelease' (for example) to a handler and then check for key symbol like this :

```
            if event.keysym=='Return' :
              event.widget.event_generate('<Tab>')
```

so how to do that on wxPYTHON ?

Comment: Perhaps you have to handle the wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER event. See here http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextCtrl.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, one solution is this:

First, use accelerator table to cache the enter key, when TextCtrl is on focus.

```
return_id = wx.NewId()
acc_table = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_RETURN, return_id)])
self.SetAcceleratorTable(acc_table)
```

Second, in event handler of the enter key, navigate to next ctrl so that move focus to next ctrl after TextCtrl.

```
ctl = wx.Window_FindFocus()
ctl.Navigate()
```

Third, if you want to disable the enter-to-tab trick, you can use wx.NullAcceleratorTable to disable this.

```
self.SetAcceleratorTable(wx.NullAcceleratorTable)
```

The full example shows as the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" Simulate Enter Key to Tab.
"""

import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=u'Test Enter to Tab Key', size=(800, 600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        base_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, '', size=(160, -1))
        base_sizer.Add(text, border=5, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        for i in range(5):
            bttn = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'Button %d' % i, size=(160, -1))
            base_sizer.Add(bttn, border=5, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        return_id = wx.NewId()
        acc_table = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_RETURN, return_id)])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(acc_table)

        wx.EVT_MENU(self, return_id, self.on_return)

        self.panel.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(base_sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def on_return(self, event):
        ctl = wx.Window_FindFocus()
        ctl.Navigate()
        # self.SetAcceleratorTable(wx.NullAcceleratorTable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    win = MainFrame()
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you added a little explanation as to what is the crux of the solution. Otherwise we're left with having to read line-by-line until we see something that might be related to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You thinking in right direction and your question have easy solution. You need to have unique name for all of your widget what you want to navigate between. After that you need to Bind every widget with one function like this:

```
self.TextCtrl_widget1.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.PushedEnter)  
self.TextCtrl_widget2.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.PushedEnter)
....
etc

def PushedEnter(self, e):
    name = e.GetEventObject().GetName()
    if name == 'TextCtrl_widget1':
        self.TextCtrl_widget2.SetFocus() # This is the next widget what you want to move focus
    elif name == 'TextCtrl_widget2':
        self.TextCtrl_widget3.SetFocus()
 etc
```